# Outlook calendar set magnification separately from scheduling increment

Tags: calendar, outlook-web-access

Using calendar on outlook web access, on week view, I set the view to 15 minute increments because I want to be able to click to schedule meetings on 15 minute intervals. But that made my calendar zoom in so that each hour is double the height that it was before. The zoomed in view is impractical because I have to scroll through to see the rest of the day. **How can I set the magnification level indepentently from the scheduling increment?** Using my browser to zoom out doesn't quite do it because that makes all the text tiny.